# Tensorflow/Keras not importing correctly on VS code 2022. Tensorflow Version == 2.8

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nameerror

No idea why this is happening but no matter what I try I can't get TensorFlow or Keras to be read properly so VScode actually sees them. No matter how I import them, it always comes up with "NameError: name 'xxx' is not defined". [Here is a photo of what is coming up:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfBMs.png)

After I try importing Tensorflow or Keras, my other imports such as "import pandas as pd" no longer work which makes me think there are some dependency issues going on? Also, when I run the import statement within the entire code block it does run successfully without the name error, but any variable that points to a keras or TensorFlow object doesn't get saved and in a new code block it says they aren't defined with another NameError.

I am using python version 3.9 and Keras/Tensorflow is the only package I have run into problems with. Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: It is likely the problem is that the jupyter kernel (that is what you are using under the hood) is crashing and the IDE is hiding that fact from you.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Yes you're right. I confirmed this by running it on jupyter and Kernel crashes everytime. I think this has something to do with M1 chip not having native support with tensorflow or something. Just Bizarre that this is an issue given how long M1 has been around.

Comment: Its simpler than that, you installed an Intel version of TensorFlow but this does not work under Rosetta due to the use of AVX instructions, solution is to install an ARM version of Tensorflow

Comment: As I can see in the mentioned screenshot, you are able to import `TensorFlow` successfully. So have you also tried importing `keras` from tensorflow like - `from tensorflow import keras`, `from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential`, from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense`. Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.